# How to use of print("HelloWorld") instead of System.out.println("Hello World");

Tags: java

I want to know how can I use just:

```
Print("statement")
```

instead of a full path like:

```
System.out.println("Statement");
```

What lib do I have to import to do this?

Comment: One simple solution is writing your own method `Print` that has `System.out.println()` inside it.

Comment: Write a method `print`. Have it call `System.out.println`. Done. You can magically fix this with `import static` but it's not recommended.

Comment: I read about import static       which helps me to write direct print.. but why is it not advisable to use import static..as a first time learner I am finding it difficult why not to use import static ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `import static`. As BorisTheSpider points out in a comment, though, wildcard static imports (like `import static java.lang.System.*;`) pollute your namespace with all the symbols of the class. This can cause subtle problems that are hard to track down. Better to explicitly list the static fields and methods you want to import.

Comment: Thank you sir, all of you helped me to understand this concept.. I am a basic learner of java and I was going through the book "Thinking in Java" and got this query. Thanks once again for all your helpful answers.

Comment: Why don't you just use `sysout`? Eclipse (and I think other IDE's too) will replace it with `System.out.println`

Comment: sir i use sysout(ctrl+space) ..but for knowledge purpose I wanted to know how can i use other way

Answer (score 1):

You can make only

```
out.println(...);
```

using

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
```

Comment: I would **strongly** recommend against `import static` and `*`. This leads to massive namespace pollution. If the OP is a beginner then this will only lead to massive confusion...

Comment: @BoristheSpider - I agree. However, it could have been `import static java.lang.System.out;`.

Comment: @TedHopp that doesn't work. System.out is an object of type PrintStream; its methods are not static.

Comment: @DavidP.Caldwell - I wasn't suggesting that the `PrintStream` methods be imported statically, just that `out` is a static field of class `System`, so it can be imported statically. That is, one can use Ivan's solution without resorting to a wildcard static import.

Comment: Good point; I read it as `import static java.lang.System.out.*;` but that wasn't what you typed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can work

```
static void print(String statement)
{
    System.out.println(statement);
}
```

Comment: To make it more general use Object as argument and add overloaded versions for primitive types as well. Oh, and use names according to Java's [naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html): "Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the **first letter lowercase**, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized."

Comment: @Pshemo If you use Object as the argument you don't need overloaded versions for primitive types.

Comment: @Boann You are right, initially I was thinking about reducing autoboxing, but after reading PrintStream code it seems that choice is between autoboxing or `Sting.valueOf()` so there is no that big difference.